# python - Send a mail (text/html) via smtplib with SSL

Tags: python, ssl, smtplib

I am trying to send a report by email using smtplib, this is my code:

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email import encoders
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

mm = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
mm["Subject"] = "Subject"
mm["From"] = ff
mm["To"] = to
mm.attach(MIMEText(msg, "html"))

srv = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('localhost', 465)
srv.sendmail(ff, to, mm.as_string())
srv.quit()
```

The content must go across SSL as report may contain sensitive data.
However, I get no error, nothing crushes, no mail in the target and no "postmaster" respond in the sender (ff) email.

I am unable to figure out what the hell I am doing wrong... The code above should be working with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6, in both environments the result is the same...

Thanks a lot

Comment: *"The content must go across SSL as report may contain sensitive data."* - SMTP does not provide end-to-end security. You only have a protected connection to the next hop (localhost in this case), from there you have no control of how the message is delivered. Every mail server in the delivery path has access to the full content of the mail. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169535/how-ssl-works-in-smtp

Comment: *"However, I get no error, nothing crushes,"* - in this case the mail is successfully delivered to your mail server at `localhost`. For further information about the mail see the logs of whatever mail server you have running there, i.e. it is outside of your code.